# How to increase the icon button of Menu in MacOS App SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui, nspopover

I want to increase the icon button of the `Menu` in SwiftUI for a macOS app, but modifiers such as `.imageScale(.large)`, `.resizable()`, `.scaleEffect(1.2)`, and changing `font` doesn't work.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q13QX.png)

```
Menu {
    Button("Quit") {}
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "gear")
        .font(.title)
        .resizable()
        .scaleEffect(1.2)
        .imageScale(.large)
}
.menuStyle(.borderlessButton)
.menuIndicator(.hidden)
```

How can I change icon size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Image`in`Text`.

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello")
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: { }) {
                    Text(Image(systemName: "gear"))
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                
                Button(action: { }) {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                }
            }
    }
}
```